# Landscape Example for Orange Box

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, orange-box

I'm using an Orange Box and have gone through the Juju bootstrap and deployed landscape as per the 01-deploy.sh script that comes with the Orange Box build, but when I go to set up a cloud in the Landscape web UI, Maas fails the check of having at least three machines with more than one disk commissioned.

I know that the NUCs in the Orange Box don't have more than one disk, but I figured that since this landscape script came bundled with the Orange Box there would be a workaround to at least try out the Landscape UI for deploying OpenStack. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: I was told you sorted this on  IRC, could you whip up an answer so we have it as part of the knowledge base? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jorge, I've been working with some people on IRC on getting Juju into a usable state with my corporate proxy on the Orange Box with some limited success, but yeah the answer given by dbp is the correct one for this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the way it is done for testing is plugging in usb sticks to all nodes.  You have to get small ones so they clear the housing when it's closed.